# How to segment part of moving image based on details from fixed image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm currently working on MRI images and each dataset consists of a series of images. All I need to do is to segment part of the moving image(s), based on details a from fixed image provided, strictly by using the image registration method.

I have tried some of the available code and done some tweaking but all I got was a warped transformation moving image based on features from the fixed image, which was correct but wasn't as I expected.

To help with the idea, here are some of those MRI images<sup>1</sup>:

Fixed image:

[image: http://www.imagesup.net/?di=813896074669]

Moving image:

[image: http://www.imagesup.net/?di=16138960757914]

The plan is to segment only total area (quadriceps, inner and outer bone sections) of the moving image as per details from the fixed image, i.e. morphologically warp the boundary of moving image according to fixed image boundary.

Any idea/suggestions as to how this could be done?

<sub>1. As a new user I'm unable to post/attach more than 2 links/images but do let me know should you need further images.</sub>

Comment: DE,

your post is a little bit out of scope; SO is for small response. 

You have an image processing (segmentation) issue you can find a lot of code at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral .

Try http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25257-color-image-segmentation for instance.

Border the answer to few possibilities, then guys will help you; at the moment the issue is too vague.

Comment: Thanks for your response venergiac. I have tried every related code at your posted links before I went here and adjusted them accordingly but still to no avail. As stated above, I'm trying to segment part of the moving image by first creating and registering the fixed image boundary (white border). My thinking is the algorithm should be able to compare the feature from this white border (could be any colour too) with feature (or any details related) to the moving image and do the segmentation accordingly (red border). Here's an example: http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1313896266994

Comment: It may be a bit late now, but I can judge from the bounty comment that the existing answer was not sufficient. However, without showing what you got from that answer and pointing out exactly what you'd want to be different it is hard to improve upon it.

Answer (score 4):

'All I need to do is to segment part of the moving image/s', this is certainly not a trivial thing to do. It is called segmentation by deformable models, and there is a lot of literature on the subject. Also, your fixed image is very different from the moved image, which doesn't help.

Here are a couple of ideas to start, but you will probably need to go into more details for your application.

```
I1=imread('fixed.png');
I2=imread('moving.png');

model=im2bw(I1,0.54);

imshowpair(I1,Model);
```

This is a simple thresholding segmentation to isolate that blob in the middle of the image. The value 0.54 was obtained by fiddling, you can certainly do a better job at segmenting your fixed image.

Here is the segmented fixed image, purple is inside, green is outside.

[image: Segmented fixed]

Now, let's deform this mask to fit the moved image:

```
masked = activecontour(I2,model, 20, 'Chan-Vese');
imshowpair(I2,masked);
```

Result:

[image]

You can automatize this in a loop along all your images, deforming each subsequent mask to the next frame. Try different parameters of `activecontour` as well.

**Edit here is another way I can think of:**

In the following code, `Istart` is the original fixed image, `Mask` is the segmented region on that image (the one you called 'fixed' in your question) and `Istep` is the moved image.

I first turned the segmented region into a binary mask, this is not strictly necessary:

```
t=graythresh(Mask);
BWmask=im2bw(Mask, t);
```

Let's display the masked original image:

```
imshowpair(BWmask, Istart)
```

[image: masked start]

The next step was to compute intensity-based registration between the start and step images:

```
[optimizer, metric] = imregconfig('monomodal');
optimizer.MaximumIterations = 300;

Tform=imregtform(Istart, Istep, 'affine', optimizer, metric);
```

And warp the mask according to this transformation:

```
WarpedMask=imwarp(BWmask, Tform, 'bicubic', 'Outputview', imref2d(size(Istart)));
```

Now let's have a look at the result:

```
imshowpair(WarpedMask, Istep);
```

[image: masked step]

It's not perfect, but it is a start. I think your main issue is that your mask contains elements that are different from each other (that middle blob vs. the darker soft tissue in the middle) If I where you, I would try to segment these structures separately.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your effort jigg. My query could be pretty vague to readers but here goes another example of what the final algorithm should be capable of: http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1313896332618

Comment: 1) Extract the fixed image boundary (as per 1st image in above link) and blend or overlap the boundary to moving image (2nd image). 2) Segment the ROI of moving image as per details from fixed image

Comment: To efficiently reduce the computation/iteration costs, I used one image within the dataset as a template (or fixed image) since the spatial information in this template could be useful prior the segmentation of other moving images within the dataset. This fixed image is also my ROI and was semi-automatically segmented but due to the time and effort limitations, ROI on moving images should be segmented automatically based on details from fixed image. Here's another example: http://www.imagesup.net/?di=3138970090110

Comment: @user3177422 Yes, I understand perfectly what you want to do. Deform the initial shape to segment the other images. If `activecontour` doesn't solve your issue, you may want to look into region growing algorithms.

Comment: Thanks jigg for your input however I've tried that one (region growing method) too and probably the solely technique that could done this right is through image registration method, which I'm very weak at.

Comment: @user3177422 can you provide the original (complete) image from which your segmented fixed image comes from? I think I might have an idea.

Comment: @user3177422 see my edits, hope it helps, I won't be able to invest any more time in this sadly.

Comment: as you said it's not perfect and although i've toyed around with imregtform function previously and the results i've got is comparable to yours but still your method is completely different, simple yet stimulating. your effort and time are greatly appreciated jigg.